# Find matrices X and Y satisfying certain properties (third variant)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

$\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}$What is the minimum integer $N$ for which there exists two $N$ by $N$ matrices $X$ and $Y$ that satisfy the following conditions:

$$\diag(X)=\diag(XYY)=\diag(YXY)=\diag(YYX)\neq \mathbf{0}$$
$$\diag(Y)=\diag(XXY)=\diag(XYX)=\diag(YXX)\neq \mathbf{0}$$
$$\diag(XY)=\diag(YX)\neq \mathbf{0}$$
$$\diag(XXYY)=\diag(XYYX)=\diag(YYXX)=\diag(XYXY)=\diag(YXYX)\neq \mathbf{0}$$

and

$\diag(X)$, $\diag(Y)$, $\diag(XY)$, and $\diag(XXYY)$ have different values.

In particular does there exist any solution for $N\leq 3$?

In the above equations, $XY$ denotes matrix multiplication (or any similar operation that is distributive and associative), $\mathbf{0}$ is the $N$ by $1$ zero vector, and $\diag(X)$ denotes the diagonal of matrix $X$.

Note this question has another variant posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3679404/find-matrices-x-and-y-satisfying-certain-properties).

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: @Robert-Israel, I am trying a numerical approach to check if the remainder of a polynomial mod $(x^2-1)$ mod $(y^2-1)$ is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $N=3$, try $$X = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & -1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & -1},\ Y = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr}$$

EDIT: 
For $N=2$, $$X = \pmatrix{-1 & 0\cr 0 & -1},\ Y = \pmatrix{-1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$$

Comment: Thanks. Is there any solution possible for $N=2$?